# "Symlink operation not permitted" error when building appImage with Electron Builder

Tags: linux, npm, electron, symlink, electron-builder

I am new to Electron and I am trying to export a game I made in a game engine. I'm accustomed to using the appImage since the engine doesn't have a native export to Linux option.

I don't know if I'm correct, I'm sort of laying blame to something relating to icons and/or that "symlink" thing just not working as it should. I'd appreciate if anyone could help me fix my issue or correct me.

This is the log from my terminal:

```
> electron-builder build --linux --x64

  • electron-builder  version=22.8.0 os=5.4.0-26-generic
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • packaging       platform=linux arch=x64 electron=9.1.2 appOutDir=dist/linux-unpacked
  • building        target=AppImage arch=x64 file=dist/game-test-1.0.0.AppImage
  ⨯ symlink usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/test-app.png /home/voy/shared/electron/test-app/dist/__appImage-x64/test-app.png: operation not permitted
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/package-format/appimage.copyIcons.func1.1
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/package-format/appimage/appLauncher.go:82
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/util.MapAsyncConcurrency.func2
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/util/async.go:68
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.2_1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373  
  ⨯ /home/voy/shared/electron/test-app/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE  stackTrace=
                                                                                                                                                  Error: /home/voy/shared/electron/test-app/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
                                                                                                                                                      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/voy/shared/electron/test-app/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:243:14)
                                                                                                                                                      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
                                                                                                                                                      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
                                                                                                                                                      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
                                                                                                                                                      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-app@1.0.0 build-linux: `electron-builder build --linux --x64`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test-app@1.0.0 build-linux script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/voy/.npm/_logs/2020-08-08T03_53_51_086Z-debug.log
```

And this is my package.json:

```
  "name": "test-app",
  "productName": "game-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\"",
    "build-installer": "electron-builder",
    "build-win": "electron-builder build --win --x64",
    "build-linux": "electron-builder build --linux --x64"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "test-app",
    "win": {
      "target": ["portable"],
      "icon": "src/icon.ico",
      "requestedExecutionLevel": "asInvoker"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": ["appImage"],
      "icon": "src/256x256.png",
      "category": "Utility"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "VoyVivika",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "test_app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {
            "name": "test_app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {
            "name": "test_app"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "electron": "9.1.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

OK so I figured out my issue. I was running my Linux in a VM and I was running the commands on a shared folder, which I assume the VM doesn't have full access to (it's a shared folder, of course it wouldn't), I copied the folder from the shared directly to a more local location in the VM and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this running my code editor (vscode) in administrator mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).